# Any way of running GTK libraries In Windows OS using C?

Tags: c, windows-7, makefile, gtk

After a whole week of trying to get GTK working on Cygwin and MinGW using makefile, I've hit a stone cold wall. Does anyone please, anyone know how I can program using C and GTK libraries in widows operating system that WORKS? If there is can anyone give me step by step instructions please! The environment has to run the hello world program as an example: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GTK%2B

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I've never heard of the 'widows' operating system before -- is it a GNU/Linux variant?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a bit tricky to configure GTK+ toolchain on Windows.

The easiest way is to use [this GTK+ bundle](http://gtk-win.sourceforge.net/home/index.php/en/Home). It provide easy to use and install GTK+ runtime environment. You will find there note how to extend this runtime for developing purposes.

According to GTK+'s mailing list version 2.16 is known to be the most stable, however maybe it's good idea to try newer one.

Moreover go to GTK+'s home page and read threads about GTK+ & Windows 7 on the gtk-app-devel mailing list.